# Which email address to use when receiving Email via AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

We want to trigger a lambda through an email.For this we have created SES rule with action as lambda, verfied domain and recipients.

```
     send email ---> SES rule ---> Lambda
```

My doubt is where i should send email from verified address to trigger this rule.I mean to which email address i should send email?

Comment: The email address you send the email to should be upto you :). Can you provide a bit more detail to help you with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Step 4: Send a Test Email - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-send.html):

> To send a test email, use an email account that you know is capable of sending email, such as your personal email address. Send a test message to any email address on your verified domain. For example, if your domain is `example.com`, you can send an email to `test@example.com` or `abc123@example.com` (or any other address on the `example.com` domain).

Comment: My Question is where to send email from verified domain.I mean to which email address i should send email to trigger rule.

Comment: To _any_ email address in the domain, as per above.

Comment: i am not getting it.Lets say i verified some.address@xxx.com and xxx.com is verified domain.Now to invoke rule with name "test-SES" i will send email from some.address@xxx.com,here what will be in "To Address" ? And how to make sure only "test-SES" is invoked  not other rules ?

Comment: This is what I can see from the documentation... There are two different processes here. When **sending emails from a sandbox account**, the recipient address must be verified. This is to prevent spam. When **receiving emails**, the domain itself is verified via DNS records. Then, any email sent to any address in that domain will be processed by SES. No individual verification of email addresses required. So, you will send the email from, for example, you@gmail.com to anything@xxx.com (your domain).

Comment: Thanks for explaination.Still one doubt i have to point MX record of my domain to SMTP endpoint which is "inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".Here no AWS account no specified.This is fine or we have to specify somewhere account no where to it will receive email?

Comment: It is fine. The MX record points to the email server. Email sent to that domain will be redirected to that server. If in doubt, follow the documentation. Please note that you should NOT point your company's normal domain to SES, otherwise nobody in your company will receive emails. You should use a different domain, or a sub-domain for SES.

Answer (score 0):

case 1 :

If you have verified domain you can trigger email using any one of email address from your verified domain

case 2 :

If you dont have verified domain you can verify your email address in aws ses console and you can use verified email address to trigger lamda

Comment: My query is where to send email ? What is destination email address ?

Comment: You must associated a **domain name** with Amazon SES (eg `example.com` or `mail.example.com`). Then, any email sent to that domain name (eg `foo@mail.example.com`) will go to Amazon SES. See: [Getting Started Receiving Email with Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html)

Comment: @John But the domain i am using is used organization wide.I cannot rout thousands of email inside the organization to SES.

Comment: In that case you have configured Amazon SES incorrectly. You need to use an `MX` record to point an entire domain to Amazon SES. For your use-case, I suggest you create a sub-domain (eg `contact.example.com`) that has an `MX` record that points to SES, then send to any email address in that domain. See: [Publishing an MX Record for Amazon SES Email Receiving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html)

Comment: @John Rotenstein Thanks for explaination.But i still have some doubts.Lets say i create subdomain "contact.example.com" and then i have to create email address for this domain like "SES.trigger@contact.example.com".Now i have to verify recipients in SES rule here "SES.trigger@contact.example.com" and then i can send email from any address like "vickey.m@gmail.com" to "SES.trigger@contact.example.com" and SES rule will be triggered.Is this correct understanding ?

Comment: While in Sandbox mode you need to verify external recipients, but you don't need to verify incoming email addresses, because you 'own' the whole domain.

Comment: @John In my above scenario i have to verify recipient as "vickey.m@gmail.com" who will be sending email  to "SES.trigger@contact.example.com" (which will trigger SES rule) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that while You were writing SES rule You mean SES Receipt Rule. While setting the receipt rule, you are configuring the actions which occur after the email was sent TO the provided recipients(in Your example it was to Your domain). So in order to trigger lambda function one of the ways to do it is to:

1. Send an email using your verified address email to different account(for instance gmail one etc.)
2. Reply to it (it will trigger rule)